# Accessing private members in JavaScript constructor

Tags: javascript, constructor

Say I have this

```
function FileHelper() {
   var _path = require("path");
}
```

I have seen 2 ways of implementing constructor methods.

```
function FileHelper() {
   var _path = require("path");

   this.getFileName = function() {
        // can reference _path here
   }
}
```

and

```
function FileHelper() {
   var _path = require("path");
}

FileHelper.prototype.getFileName = function () {
    // cannot reference _path here
}
```

I'm leaning towards "attaching" the implementation of methods to the contructor's prototype, and would like to, if possible, keep any dependencies contained within the constructor itself, as opposed to declaring them as globals in the constructor's file.

with that said, is there a way to achieve the following?

```
function FileHelper() {
   var _path = require("path");
}

FileHelper.prototype.getFileName = function (filePath) {
    // _path is successfully referenced without reference error
    return _path.basename(filePath);
}
```

Comment: No there is no way to do that. A variable declared inside a function is scoped to that function (and any functions declared inside it). You can of course attach `_path` to `this` to make it a property of the constructed object, but it's not really "private" then.

Comment: I was afraid there would be no way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with that said, is there a way to achieve the following?

No. The `_path` declared in the constructor is a local variable. It's entirely private to the constructor and goes away after the constructor terminates, since the constructor doesn't create any closures that would retain it.

If you want to keep using it, either:

1. Create `getFileName` in the constructor, so it closes over it, or
2. Save it as a property on the instance (`this`) and then use it from that property

---

Have said that: Accessing something via `require` within a constructor seems like a bit of an antipattern. Since it won't change, just access it outside the constructor, for instance:

```
var FileHelper = (function() {
    var _path = require("path");

    function FileHelper() {
    }
    FileHelper.prototype.getFileName = function() {
        // ...use _path here...
    };

    return FileHelper;
})();
```

(I've kept that at ES5-level syntax because your question seems to be avoiding using ES2015+)

Comment: why is there an empty function declaration of `FileHelper` inside the IIFE?
Could't you just reference `FileHelper` within the IIFE without the empty function declaration?

Comment: @jsdev17 - You have to declare the function. The other function isn't `FileHelper`, it's an IIFE executed immediately (and just once) to get the execution context where we store `_path`. What the structure above (called the *revealing module pattern*) does is provide a private static scope for anything related to `FileHelper`.